# AQL Query returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, promise, aql

I have been trying to get a query result from Arangodb in to my front end service(Angular 4) using soap message. I am able to get a result of the query but printed out in console.log. But how can I get it under this function(myService).
In other words, How can I feed my query result into a function rather than printing out the result in console. So that I can use this function to get the output of the query?

I have used .then() as well in order to get the promise.What am I still missing in it ?

**server.js**

```
var myService = db.query(aqlQuery`
                LET startVertex = (FOR doc IN spec
                FILTER doc.serial_no == '"123456abcde"'
                LIMIT 2
                RETURN doc
                )[0]

               FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to
               RETURN v.ip`,
               {
                 bindVar1: 'value',
                 bindVar2: 'value',
               })..then(function(res) {
                   console.log("documents:" + res._result);
            })
```

I would like to feed the function into soap msg and receive it Angular 4,

**soap msg**

```js
var soap_msg = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:examples:CheckUserNameService">' +
  '<soapenv:Header/>' +
  '<soapenv:Body>' +
  '<urn:CheckUserNameResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
  '<status xsi:type="xsd:string">' + (myService) + '</status>' +
  '</urn:CheckUserNameResponse>' +
  '</soapenv:Body>' +
  '</soapenv:Envelope>';
  
var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end(soap_msg);
});

var port = 8000;
server.listen(port);
var soapServer = soap.listen(server, '/test', myService, xml);
```

But the output is either empty braces If I am using JSON.stringify or else it is [object Promise]. What am I doing wrong here ?

**output**
[image]

Comment: Well the only place we see a console.log is in the error case of your call. How is soapCallback defined? It seems that you already have what you want and just have to extend soapCallBack to fit your needs

Comment: @Glubus I would like to feed the myService into a soapmsg but the result of query is object Object. If I use stringify to the soap message then it is empty {}

Comment: Looks like `aqlQuery` returns a promise and you will need to wait for taht

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't build XML like that. There are SOAP implementations for node, ideally pick one of them. The next best thing to do would be to prepare an empty SOAP response in an XML file, load that into a DOM and put the values into it with DOM methods. But at the *very* least, XML-encode the value if you absolutely must do string concatenation.

Comment: @Bergi it is an aqlquery..,What do you mean by wait for that

Comment: @Tomalak No I have my wsdl file as well..,this is just server side in node and the client side is from angular 4.I didnt add those to it .,because it is not necessary iguess